# Placing points on circle with same distance always beginning at same point

Tags: ios, math

I already know how to place the points with same distance on top of a circle:

```
double slice = 2 * M_PI / [icons count];    
for (int i = 0; i < [icons count]; i++)
{
    double angle = slice * i;
    int newX = (int)(cen.x + rad * cos(angle));
    int newY = (int)(cen.y + rad * sin(angle));
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
}
```

Depending on the number of elements in my array the position of the points is always different (of course) but how can I manage to put the first point always at the same spot on the circle e.g. at the top most point of the circle?

Comment: It always will be. When `i` is 0, your point will always be (cen.x + rad, cen.y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constant value to your angle. The points should start out on the right of the origin (in standard cartesian coordinates where 0,0 is in the center and X and Y increase to the right and up.)

To shift the first point to the top, add pi/2 to your angle.

It looks like you're using iOS coordinates, where 0,0 is at the top left of the sceen and Y increases DOWN, which flips normal cartesian coordinates on the X axis. Thus you'd need to subtract pi/2 from the angle:

```
double slice = 2 * M_PI / [icons count];    
for (int i = 0; i < [icons count]; i++)
{
    double angle = slice * i - M_PI_2;
    int newX = (int)(cen.x + rad * cos(angle));
    int newY = (int)(cen.y + rad * sin(angle));
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
}
```